# Flash .rom file to BIOS chip

Tags: software-rec, bios, updates, flashing, rom

I have got a .rom file from my BIOS chip using [this](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/9856-Universal-BIOS-Backup-Toolkit) tool (it really isn't a virus). I extracted the Packard Bell boot logo from it using CBROM, edited it and put it back into the .rom, which surprisingly worked. Now I got this .rom file, but how do I get it onto my BIOS chip? I tried putting it on a USB disk and updating it from the BIOS settings, but it had no updater. I am actually not really sure of what brand my mobo is. CPU-Z says it's made by Packard Bell, but I am not sure if they make mobo's. Packard Bell does not have a update utility, actually they don't even have BIOS updates on their website, and my model is not on their FTP server (which is actually some sort of a trash bin).
I searched half the internet for this.
My system specifications and all mobo-related stuff can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/9rBSZMYg).

It seems that my system is PACKARD BELL iSTART F9240 with OEM Gigabyte GA-T671MG motherboard. [OEM BIOS Link](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/BIOS/desktop_bios_sis671_t671mg.f5.rar.zip)

Comment: Can anyone please help me? I really don't know how to solve this.

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve by updating your BIOS?  If you don't know how to flash your BIOS you really shouldn't flash your BIOS, if you do it wrong you can place your system in an unbootable situation which cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Ramhound There is no real problem, I just want to change my logo. I am a very experienced computer user and I know what I'm doing. And if I somehow screw things up, I just buy a new BIOS chip. You should try everything with computers to become an expert (if I'm not already).

Comment: You should be able to flash the BIOS by loading a bootable disk that runs the loader program.

Comment: @Ramhound Could you please give me an example? I can't really find good ones...

Comment: Example of what exactly?  If you don't know how to flash your BIOS you will not be successful and brick your computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with finding proper flashing utility is that there are multiple ways a BIOS flash chip could be connected to the motherboard in. Usually it is using interfaces like LPC/FWH/SPI/etc. Then there are flash chips from different chip manufacturers, many of which while supposed to be standard are in fact require slightly different flashing procedures. Then there are different BIOS Vendors which have different formats and therefore different flashing utilities which have to account for the format differences.

If you are still eager to screw up your motherboard - start with opening your BIOS image with a hex editor and look for the BIOS vendor patterns like "ami", "award", "phoenix" - then look for the flashing utility from the vendor whose name you found. You may have to try multiple versions before you find one recognizing the flash chip on your motherboard.

I edited your question to include the system's manufacturer/model name and OEM of the motherboard. Packard Bell is no help and Gigabyte does not support the OEM boards. At least Gigabyte provided the generic (Award/Phoenix) BIOS for the board. It did not come with any flashing utility which might mean that there is a flashing facility in the BIOS itself (which could be missing from the BIOS that Packard Bell put in their systems)